# How to add a new field to a specific Document in Firebase/Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to add a new field to an already existing document through clicking a button on an app. In this case, a parent wants to add a child name to their account so they type their child's name and click a button that would add the name to the documents field, [example of document info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6NwJ.png). The .add option is only available whenever I try to edit all collections, but I want it to be unique for each one as not all parents have the same amount of children.

```
final String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').id;
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(id)
```

This is how I have setup now to access the individual user document.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add new field...

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id)
    .update({'key': 'value'})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_8).